# Can't Import Classes From Added Jar File In Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

Hi I'm working on Android app and I need to use an API which I'm only able to work with using a Jar. I add the Jar by copy/pasting the Jar into the libs folder and then choosing the "Add as Library" option.

The problem is I can't import any of the classes included in the Jar file.

The directory structure for the Jar looks like this.

```
*libs
  |-->semantics3-api
       |-->com.semantics3
             |-->api
                  |-->Products.java
                  |-->...
             |-->errors
                  |-->Util.java
             |-->Util.java
```

So for example if I try to import the Products class by saying "import com.semantics3.api.Products;" I get a "symbol not found error" on the word Products in that line and anytime I try to make a Products object.

The odd thing is when writing the import statement Android Studio will offer * as the only autocomplete option to import everything under the com.semantics3 or api folders (so "import com.semantics3.*" or "import com.semantics3.api.*") but even if I do that I can't utilize the classes.

Has anyone experienced something similar when working with added Jar files in Android Studio? How can I go about fixing this? I appreciate any help with this, thank you.

Could it be an issue with my Jar file potentially? I used the jar command in the terminal to generate the jar from the source code if that helps.

Comment: I've just started to encounter the issue and was wondering if you ever found a solution? Was the issue with your Jar file? I'll post my findings if I come across an answer while debugging the issue.